# Need to run alert a string using javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to alert `is it executed well?` after following line is executed in javascript

`window["is"]("it")("executed")("well")("?")`

window here means a global object. I have no idea what that above line is in javascript.

Comment: Is that actually valid JavaScript? Have you tried executing it to see what happens?

Comment: For what it's worth, this is valid Javascript (functions can return functions), but I'm at a loss to explain why something so convoluted would be written...

Comment: I'm trying to create a recursive function for this, but failing miserably. Can't check if a function will be executed, from within the function, of course...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evil recursion :)

`arguments.callee` refers to the function you are currently calling.

```
window.is = (function(len){
    var buffer = ["is"];
    return function(str) {
        buffer.push(str);
        if(buffer.length === len) {
            alert(buffer.join(" "));
        }
        else {
            return arguments.callee;            
        }
    }
}(5));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/wf8ag/

Comment: It works too. Could you please tell me what is arguments.callee? Also could you explain your approach. Thanks

Comment: You actually made it work recursively, nice! Only too bad you have to supply it's length.

Comment: I agree. Nifty solution for a terrible problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
window.is = function(it){
    return function(executed){
        return function(well){
            return function(questionMark){
              alert("is "+it+" "+executed+" "+well+" "+questionMark);
            }
        }
    }
}

window["is"]("it")("executed")("well")("?")​
```

strange question. there's probably a more efficient way of doing it...

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jd3uM/

Comment: I like yours a bit more since you didn't use `is` as a string when defining the function. But yeah, this is a super weird question.

Comment: It works thanks. Could you explain what this line means in js?

Comment: Also, how funny is it that we used exactly the same parameter names lol.

Comment: @x4f4r: `window.is` Is a function that returns a function that returns a function that returns a function. These functions all accept parameters, which are being concatenated in the "deepest" function.
Still following? No? That's why `window["is"]("it")("executed")("well")("?")​` is a bad idea.

Comment: @ahren It is a question which was asked by someone(interviewer) from me. I could not answer this question at that time but now wanted to know what it is and how to solve it. :(

Answer (score 0):

The following works, although I can't think of any possible use for something that ugly.

```
window["is"] = function (it) {
   return function (executed) {
      return function (well) {
          return function (questionMark) {
              alert("is " + it + " " + executed + " " + well + questionMark);
          }
      }
   }
}
```

The first thing is to add the `is` element to the `window` array (oh my…) and then keep returning functions that will be called.